# How to trigger numerous Jenkins jobs in parallel avoiding those receiving same job ID?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I got main job that receives items list, I need to trigger another job for each item passing the item as parameter. The job that triggered for each Item is the same job for all. For main job I use Jenkins file as followed

```
def run_items=[:]
for (item in items_list){
        run_items[item]={
         build wait: true,job: 'items_job', parameters: [
         string(name: 'Item', value: item)
    ]
}
parallel run_items
```

The logic for the main job is working the problem is that all parallel triggered item instances triggering same single instance of items job.
It happening because of how `build` command works, it getting the next job id first, since I gout numerous parallel commands those receive the same next build number. How can it be solved?

Comment: [`build` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job) has optional `quietperiod`; *quiet period (in seconds) **before** building*. Tried that? `wait` is "wait for the result of the build step before jumping to the next step".

Comment: @IanW yeah, not working
using same quit period for all jobs

Comment: Wait for "*n* x [index of job element in items_list] "? Otherwise, you were just delaying the collision *n* secs.

Comment: Alao, rather than `for` loop, `items_list.each { ... }` is preferred as safer.

Comment: @IanW : could you link a reference to elaborate on that `for` vs. `each` recommendation ? thanks much in advance.

Comment: @patrice-m, I am not an expert in the matter .., but like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1014334/how-to-use-for-loop-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline). Loops have all sorts of issues (eg: [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-26481), [JENKINS-55426](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-55426)) . Good [detail here](https://gist.github.com/oifland/ab56226d5f0375103141b5fbd7807398), though Jenkins scalability best practices specifically [suggests c++ iterators](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/01/pipeline-scalability-best-practice/). ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks again @IanW , this is related to the non-serializable aspect of the `each` construct, while `for` loops don't run into that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had exactly this problem, It seemed it was having it in the for in loop  that was the problem, although I don't know why. Changing to the iterator style of loop seemed to fix the problem.

I have modified your code block in a similar way to which I modified mine to get it working, which was just looping through iteratively and declaring an item in the loop by using the index instead.

An assumption is it has something to do with an issue with for in loops https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-55426, many of the credits for this answer go to people in the comments, I just pieced it together based on what they said really

```
def run_items=[:]
for (i = 0; i < items_list.size(); i+= 1){
        def item = items_list[i]
        run_items["${item.someProperty}"]={
         build wait: true,job: 'items_job', parameters: [
         string(name: 'Item', value: item)
    ]
}
parallel run_items
```